# Kotlin in the forEach, why it can be reassigned if it is an array?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I found out a weird situation when I was solving the problem in Leetcode.
Normal

```
var a = listOf(1,2,3)
a.forEach{it++}
```

Obviously, compiler shows it can not be reassigned.
However!!
Why it works in the below situation?

```
//An 2 by 2 matrix :[[0,0],[0,0]]
val matrix = Array(2,init = {IntArray(2,init = {0})})
matrix.forEach {it[0]++}
//get a new matrix : [[1,0],[0,0]]
```

matrix has been reassigned right?
Can someone tell me about what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `it[0]++` is syntactic sugar for writing `it.set(0, it.get(0) + 1)`. You're not trying to assign a value to the read-only value `it`. You are calling a function on an object.

Answer (score 1):

`matrix` val isn't reassigned here, and moreover it can't be reassigned because it's declared as `val`. You can verify it pretty easily:

```
val matrix = Array(2,init = {IntArray(2,init = {0})})
val originalMatrix = matrix
matrix.forEach {it[0]++}

println(matrix === originalMatrix) // prints true
```

But what happens instead?

`matrix` is an object here or, more specifically, an array, whose elements are arrays as well. In the expression `matrix.forEach { it ... }`, `it` is a matrix element, and its type is `IntArray`. Finally, `it[0]++` is the same as `it[0] = it[0] + 1`, so for `IntArray` it's a perfectly valid operation that increments its first `Int` element's value.

Comment: I can not accept both answers.  You are also right. To modify an IntArray actually is an action to call its 'set' function.